# Adding data from .txt document to array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, concatenation

Below is what the text document looks like. The first line is the number of elements that I want the array to contain. The second is the ID for the product, separated by # and the third line is the total price of the products once again separated by #

```
10
PA/1234#PV/5732#Au/9271#DT/9489#HY/7195#ZR/7413#bT/4674#LR/4992#Xk/8536#kD/9767#
153#25#172#95#235#159#725#629#112#559#
```

I want to use the following method to pass `inputFile` to the `readProductDataFile` method:

```
public static Product[] readProductDataFile(File inputFile){
    // Code here
}
```

I want to create an array of size 10, or maybe an arrayList. Preferably to be a concatenation of Customer ID and the price, such as Array[1] = PA/1234_153

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go the full class, does exactly what you want:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
class myRead{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt")); 
        String numberOfElements = inputFile.readLine();
        //this is the first line which contains the number "10"
        //System.out.println(numberOfElements);
        String secondLine = inputFile.readLine();
        //this is the second line which contains your data, split it using "#" as a delimiter
        String[] strArray = secondLine.split("#");
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
        //System.out.println(strArray[0]);
        String thirdLine = inputFile.readLine();
        //this is the third line which contains your data, split it using "#" as a delimiter
        String[] dataArray = thirdLine.split("#");
        //combine arrays
        String[] combinedArray = new String[strArray.length];
        for (int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++) {
        combinedArray[i]=strArray[i]+"_"+dataArray[i];
        System.out.println(combinedArray[i]);
        }
}
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
PA/1234_153
PV/5732_25
Au/9271_172
DT/9489_95
HY/7195_235
ZR/7413_159
bT/4674_725
LR/4992_629
Xk/8536_112
kD/9767_559
```

The trick in what I am doing is using a `BufferedReader` to read the file, `readLine` to read each of the three lines, `split("#");` to split each token using the `#` as the delimiter and create the arrays, and `combinedArray[i]=strArray[i]+"_"+dataArray[i];` to put the elements in a combined array as you want...!

```
public static Product[] readProductDataFile(File inputFile){
BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
// the rest of my previous code goes here
```

EDIT: Everything together with calling a separate method from inside the main, with the file as an input argument!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
class myRead{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File myFile = new File("test.txt"); 
        readProductDataFile(myFile);
        }
        public static String[] readProductDataFile(File inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt")); 
        String numberOfElements = myReader.readLine();
        //this is the first line which contains the number "10"
        //System.out.println(numberOfElements);
        String secondLine = myReader.readLine();
        //this is the second line which contains your data, split it using "#" as a delimiter
        String[] strArray = secondLine.split("#");
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
        //System.out.println(strArray[0]);
        String thirdLine = myReader.readLine();
        //this is the third line which contains your data, split it using "#" as a delimiter
        String[] dataArray = thirdLine.split("#");
        //combine arrays
        String[] combinedArray = new String[strArray.length];
        for (int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++) {
        combinedArray[i]=strArray[i]+"_"+dataArray[i];
        System.out.println(combinedArray[i]);
}
        return combinedArray;
}
}
```

OUTPUT

```
PA/1234_153
PV/5732_25
Au/9271_172
DT/9489_95
HY/7195_235
ZR/7413_159
bT/4674_725
LR/4992_629
Xk/8536_112
kD/9767_559
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense, surely String secondLine = inputFile.readLine(); is just going to read the whole file again and not the second line..

Comment: It makes perfect sense. I wrote the whole class which prints the element that you want `PA/1234` .. just compile and run the class and see for your self..

Comment: See my edit, does exactly what you want, even concatenates the two arrays using the "_" symbol like you want...

Comment: Ahh I understand, thank you. I also struggle with the concept of what to pass. In my case I want to pass to the method type file, whereas in your example you have used FileReader

Comment: You can pass the file as an argument, and then read it as I do and create the Arrays and everything.. Accept my answer  as described here : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and if you have another question then post another question..

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I asked how to do it using the specific parameters.     public static Product[] readProductDataFile(File inputFile){
//Code here
}

Comment: I hope you are kidding, just pass the file as an argument to your method which should do exactly what my code is doing: `File myFile = new File("test.txt");`

Comment: I'm not kidding. Yes I did that. however how do I then use the buffered reader alongside the File class?

Comment: see my edit. what is so complicated for you? it is the same thing exactly

Comment: Thankyou man, works perfectly. Sorry for being stubborn but its these little things that I can't get my head round

Comment: Lol, no worries. Glad I could convince you that it does indeed what you want after all :D

Comment: Can I ask one more question man? you know when saving it as an array and concatenating it. Is it possible to have the two fields corresponding in the array allowing me to reference to each individual one rather than just a string of it put together. So what I mean is can I access the price by itself or the customers id by itself but store them in the same array?

Comment: You will need to get the element and then split it two, unless you also keep them in separate arrays (as I also did). Post a new question if you want.. you can ask unlimited questions there is no limit :D

Comment: Yeah got to wait 90 minutes though!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need the first line. Just read the second line directly into a single string and then split it by using String,split() method.

[Read more for split method here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: Okay so how would I put this into an array?

Comment: Look the link I provided you. The function declaration is "public String[] split(String regex)" . It returns a String array. Just do:
String[] myArray = lineYouReadFromFile.split("#");

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this (Be aware that i can't test it at the moment)

```
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileeditor.txt"));
    String read = null;
    String firstLine=in.readLine();
   //reads the first line
    while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
   // reads all the other lines 
        read = in.readLine();
        String[] splited = read.split("#");
        //split the readed row with the "#" character
        for (String part : splited) {
            System.out.println(part);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        //close file
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it using Java (don't forget to import):

```
public static Product[] readProductDataFile(File inputFile){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(inputFile);
    String data = "";
    while(s.hasNext())
        data += s.nextLine();
String[] dataArray = data.split("#");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way ..
Reading line by line and storing each row in a array.
Use while storing so it will split and save .

```
String[] strArray = secondLine.split("#");
```

Now use the for loop and concat the values as u wish and save ina third array .

```
For(int i=0 ;i< file.readline;i++)
{
   string s = a[customerid];
   s.concat(a[productid]);
a[k] =s;
}
```